React useState not automatically re-rendering to reflect an updated object in my database
I'm working on my first React project where I'm implementing a shopping cart feature. When a user clicks on a button to increase the quantity of an item in their cart, I update the quantity in the MongoDB database through my backend route (addCart). After updating the quantity in the database, I want to re-render the component to reflect the changes in the total price, but the state isn't updating accordingly.

I have a cartItems state that holds multiple objects representing items in the user's cart.
When the user clicks the button to increase the quantity (handleAddCounter function), I call quantityUpdater to update the quantity in the database.
After updating the quantity in the database, I update the cartItems state and call calculateTotalPrice to update the total price.
However, the total price doesn't reflect the updated quantity until I refresh the page.
I suspect that the issue lies in how I'm updating the state after the database change. Could someone please guide me on how to correctly update the state and trigger a re-render after updating the database?

//My states and their initial values
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]); //This currently holds multiple objects
const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);

//Button that adds to the quantity
<button className='inline-flex items-center justify-center font-medium text-xl text-slate-600 mx-2 h-8 w-8 hover:border hover:bg-gray-300 hover:border-gray-300 hover:rounded-full' onClick={() => {handleAddCounter(item.productId, item.productImage, item.productTitle, item.productPrice, item.productSize, item.quantity)}}>+</button>

//Trying to run fetch data and calculate price on each re-render
useEffect(() => {
        fetchCartData();
        //Running calculate total price to get the new value from the state
        calculateTotalPrice();
    }, [cartItems]);

//Updating the quantity
const handleAddCounter = (prodId, img, title, price, size, quantity) => {
const updatedQuantity = quantity + 1;
quantityUpdater(prodId, img, title, price, size, quantity, updatedQuantity);}

//Sending that to the back end
const quantityUpdater = async (prodId, img, title, price, size, quantity, updatedQuantity) => {
try {
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
console.log('Getting token from singleProduct: ', token);
const showUserName = username;console.log('Seeing if username has a value: ', showUserName);
const showProductId = prodId;console.log('Seeing if product id has a value: ', showProductId);

        if (!token) {
            throw new Error('Authentication token not found');
        }

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/auth/user/addCart', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,

            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                productId: prodId,
                img: img,
                title: title,
                price: price,
                size: size,
                quantity: updatedQuantity,
                username,
            }),
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Network response error: ${response.statusText}`);
        }

        // Update cartItems state with the new data (forcing state to re-render because it doesn't recognize an updated object)
        // React only recognizes a state change when the state is se t with a new object
        const updatedCartItems = cartItems.map(item => {
            if (item.productId === prodId && item.productSize === size) {
                // Update quantity for matching product ID and size
                return {
                    ...item,
                    quantity: updatedQuantity
                };
            }
            // Return unchanged item for other items
            return item;
        });

        setCartItems(updatedCartItems);
        calculateTotalPrice();
        console.log('Calculate Total price fired!');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding to cart: ', error.message);
    }
};

 //Calculating the total price 
const calculateTotalPrice = () => { 
console.log('Calculate total price received and running'); 
// Check if cart is defined and is an array 
if (cartItems && Array.isArray(cartItems)) { 
let addedValue = 0; 
console.log('This is to check the calculated price to see if cartItems is actually printing something worth while: ', cartItems); 
for (let i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) { 
// Check if cart[i] is not undefined before accessing its properties 
if (cartItems[i] && cartItems[i].productPrice) { addedValue += cartItems[i].productPrice; } }
setTotalPrice(addedValue);

        console.log('Is total Price updating the price?: ', totalPrice);
    } else {
        setTotalPrice(0);
    }
}

//Back end to create new item or update an existing object 
router.post('/addCart', authenticate, async (req, res) => { 
const { productId, img, title, price, size, quantity, username } = req.body; 
//Extracting product information from 
console.log('Product ID in route:', productId); 
console.log('IMG in route:', img); 
console.log('title in route:', title); 
console.log('Price in route:', price); 
console.log('Size in route:', size); 
console.log('Quantity in route:', quantity); 
console.log('username in route:', username); 
// Extract productId from req.body 
const isProductIdANum = req.body.productId; console.log('Type of productId:', typeof isProductIdANum);
//Price being manipulated below
let newPrice;

// Check if they exist, I don't want to go further if they don't
if (!productId || !img || !title || !price || !size || !quantity || !username) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Missing required fields' });
}

try {
    //Querying the username field in the user collection
    const user = await User.findOne({ username });

    if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
    }

    //Check for existing cart item
    //The productId being produced from req.body is a string so we converted it back to int
    const existingCartItem = user.cart.find(item => item.productId === parseInt(productId));
    const existingSize = user.cart.find(item => item.productSize === parseInt(size));

    if (existingCartItem && existingSize) {
        //Changing the quantity value instead of adding another object
        console.log('Existing item found!: ', existingCartItem);
        //Storing the original price 
        const originalPrice = existingCartItem.productPrice / existingCartItem.quantity;
        console.log('Original Price: ', originalPrice);

        //updating the quantity
        existingCartItem.quantity = quantity;
        console.log('Quantity: ', quantity);

        //Price Based on Quantity
        newPrice = originalPrice * quantity;
        console.log('New Price: ', newPrice)

        existingCartItem.productPrice = newPrice;
    } else {
        // Adding the product to the cart
        productPrice = price * quantity;
        user.cart.push({ productId, productImage: img, productTitle: title, productPrice: productPrice, productSize: size, quantity: quantity });
    }
    await user.save();

    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Product added successfully to cart' });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error adding to cart: ', error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Could not add to cart' });
}

});

State updates are asynchronous; your code attempts uses a state value before it’s been updated.

I've been trying to figure out how to fix it, if I refresh the page it updates so I began to realize that but I have no idea how to get the value to update and get pushed to the state in time.

Since totalPrice can be directly calculated from the cart, it should not be its own state. Instead, calculate it during rendering. This will reduce the number of renders, make it impossible for the states to be out of sync, and as a bonus it will fix the issue you're running into where your calculation is using stale closure variables.
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
let totalPrice = 0;
if (cartItems && Array.isArray(cartItems)) {
  for (let i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
    if (cartItems[i] && cartItems[i].productPrice) {
      totalPrice += cartItems[i].productPrice;
    }
  }
}

If the calculation is expensive, you can wrap it in useMemo so it will only recalculate when the cartItems change.
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
const totalPrice = useMemo(() => {
  let totalPrice = 0;
  if (cartItems && Array.isArray(cartItems)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
      if (cartItems[i] && cartItems[i].productPrice) {
        totalPrice += cartItems[i].productPrice;
      }
    }
  }
  return totalPrice;
}, [cartItems]);


Thanks for this, it made me realize that the underlying issue is my cartItems state not reflecting the updated price until I refresh the page. The calculations for the pricing is done in the back-end and then saved to the db so I need to figure out a way to let cartItems realize there is a change and re-render the state.

I firgured it out, the state was one thing but I realized in my database I wasn't returning any data, now it updates accordingly.
I added a res.json with my cart information in my post route.
